# How do I find integer solutions for the following inequality

Tags: inequality, conic-sections, integers

I have to write an algorithm to find all integer solutions to inequalities of the form  $ax^2+by\leq c$, for example $-x^2+3y<7$, with constraints on x and y like $15\leq x\leq 31$ and $63\leq y\leq 92$.

A possible way is to loop over all x, calculate y and verify if it's integer, but is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Find where
equality holds in
$ax^2+bx \le c$
by solving
$ax^2+bx - c=0$.

By looking at the shape
of the curve,
decide whether
the inequality holds
between or outside
the roots.

Combine this with the
other constraints on $x$
and then use the fact
that you are looking for
integers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's a two variables inequalitie

Comment: I don't think 'looking at the curve' is much of an algorithmic solution.

Comment: Look at $f''$, which is constant for a quadratic.

Comment: It' a two variables inequalitie, the objectif is to find the couples of integers (x,y) that solve the inequalitie